# Incorrect connection string causing hangup in c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've got a question in regards to connection strings.
I've got SQLExpress installed on my desktop PC and also on my laptop.
I'm currently trying to move a program from my pc to the laptop and I'm running into quite a few troubles there. All seemingly connected to the connection string I'm using.

Whenever I'm running the program (connection string below) on the Desktop PC it functions without problems.

```
SQLExpress Server name: TOM-PC1\SQLEXPRESS

<add name="DefaultConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=TOM-PC1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Caching;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Whenever I'm trying to run the program on the laptop (connection string below) I have the problem that it stops when it tries to create the connection (code for that further below).

```
SQLExpress SErver name: N060B000
    <add name="DefaultConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=./N060B000;Initial Catalog=Caching;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

When I modify the connection string so that the DataSource=N060B000
then the hanging problem doesn't occur, but I suddenly get data binding errors immediately and the program stops.

Does anyone have an idea here what I'm doing wrong?
(also it would interest me what I'm doing wrong in regards to the connection creation itself as it was not planed that the con.Open leads to the program hanging up for minutes) tnx

Code for creation of the connection:

```
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(this.connectionStr);
            con.Open();
            command.Connection = con;
            return command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
```

Note: I'm using .Net 2012 express (desktop) and mssql server 2012 express.

Comment: Have you tried using ip address for Data Source = xx.xx.xx.xx instead of connectionString="Data Source=./N060B000 ?

Comment: you mean 127.0.0.1 as example? (the program and the sql server are on the same laptop)

If I put in Data Source=127.0.0.1    I get a hangup again

Comment: If you db version is express one, the format should be Data Source = ServerName\[SQLExpress instance]

Comment: Yepp its express. 
What really confuses me there also is that I used default setting with both installations but on the desktop I got TOM-PC1 as part of the sql-server name (which is the computers name), and then sqlexpress while on the laptop I ONLY got the computers name as name for the sql-server. 

Also like mentioned: When I use DataSource=N060B000 on the laptop the program doesnt hang any longer, but instead I get binding errors (but the database is exactly the same as on the desktop)

Comment: what is binding error message?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type "System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException" occured in PresentationFramework.dll

"The invocation of the constructor on type 'Myproject.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception Line number 7 and line position 70

whereas the call stack only contained external code when I said break.

Comment: The message is not db connection issue. Are you sure code is the same as in your PC and laptop? Program is working in PC, but not in laptop though same code?

Comment: yepp. Absolutely sure. I put the code up into a shared drive and run it once from laptop and once from desktop.  laptop results as above, desktop it functions without problems. 

Only thing that is different is that the database is 64 bit on desktop and 32 on laptop (although no clue why not 64 bit there) and the different names for the machine itself and the sql server. 
But that aside all other things are the same (same data, same database layout, same code)

Comment: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException seem.. there is invalid data for XML string. Why don't you check data? Any data like &, <, etc?

Comment: Shouldn't your local instance name be .\N060B000 instead of ./N060B000?

Comment: Found the data binding error (was a null value in the second db). 
Thus back to the original question. 
@JaneD: you are right there. could that have resulted in the hangup? (database access functions if I use only N060B000 [with the corrected data], thus original question is why the program hangs up on connect with the incorrect connection string instead of throwing an exception (as expected))

Comment: If you have an escaped character, then sure it could cause you issues.  I don't know if it would cause a hangup, but it certainly might do something silly :)